# Cannot find duration__rosidl_typesupport_connext_c

Tags: ros, makefile

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I am trying to compile ROS2 builtin_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_c.dir/rosidl_typesupport_c for a non supported DDS and I am hurting this error:

```
[ 46%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/builtin_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_c.dir/rosidl_typesupport_c/builtin_interfaces/msg/duration__type_support.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/builtin_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_c.dir/rosidl_typesupport_c/builtin_interfaces/msg/time__type_support.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++   -Dbuiltin_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_c_EXPORTS -I/ros2_src/build/builtin_interfaces/rosidl_typesupport_c -I/ros2_src/build/builtin_interfaces/rosidl_typesupport_connext_c -I/ros2_src/install/include -I/ros2_src/build/builtin_interfaces/rosidl_generator_c  -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -g -fPIC   -Wall -std=gnu++14 -o CMakeFiles/builtin_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_c.dir/rosidl_typesupport_c/builtin_interfaces/msg/duration__type_support.cpp.o -c /ros2_src/build/builtin_interfaces/rosidl_typesupport_c/builtin_interfaces/msg/duration__type_support.cpp
/usr/bin/c++   -Dbuiltin_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_c_EXPORTS -I/ros2_src/build/builtin_interfaces/rosidl_typesupport_c -I/ros2_src/build/builtin_interfaces/rosidl_typesupport_connext_c -I/ros2_src/install/include -I/ros2_src/build/builtin_interfaces/rosidl_generator_c  -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -g -fPIC   -Wall -std=gnu++14 -o CMakeFiles/builtin_interfaces__rosidl_typesupport_c.dir/rosidl_typesupport_c/builtin_interfaces/msg/time__type_support.cpp.o -c /ros2_src/build/builtin_interfaces/rosidl_typesupport_c/builtin_interfaces/msg/time__type_support.cpp
/ros2_src/build/builtin_interfaces/rosidl_typesupport_c/builtin_interfaces/msg/duration__type_support.cpp:16:77: fatal error: builtin_interfaces/msg/duration__rosidl_typesupport_connext_c.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I cannot find where the duration__rosidl_typesupport_connext_c.h is generated. Could you tell me where it is?

Thanks :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276577/cannot-find-duration__rosidl_typesupport_connext_c/) by [pokitoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/32070/pokitoz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 527 on 2017-11-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found it.

It was under rosidl_default_generators/rosidl_default_generators-extras.cmake.in

set(_exported_dependencies
HERE
)

And I forgot to add my dependency.

---

Originally posted by [pokitoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/32070/pokitoz/) with karma: 527 on 2017-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1